# PDF/E Writing with Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

ISO 24517-1:2008 Specifies a subset called PDF/E. Its usage is aimed for engineering and technical documentation and the rationale is long term preservation.

My question is, is there a PDFWriter for Java that writes PDF/E compliant documents?

iText doesn't support yet: 
"There’s no direct support for PDF/E in iText yet. But there’s already some functional-ity added that will be mandatory for PDF/UA" 
-iText in Action, 2nd ed

Links:

http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/pdfs/pdf-eready-guide-ue.pdf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/E
http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/pdf-why-and-how-itext-5/

Comment: From the sounds of it the tools able to handle PDF/A would be the first place where I'd look.

Comment: You're linking to a book. And it does *not* seem to be an authorized, public copy of this book. Please don't do that.

Comment: OK, I found another site with same quote though.. Is that grey area?

Comment: Quoting a short passage from a book is legal almost everywhere and definitely more welcome. But the new link still seems to be show a significant portion. Why don't you simply quote that text from the book and leave the link out?

Comment: Yep. I think this question will resolve if and when iText adds the feature. I don't expect much from other implementations.

Comment: Link to copyrighted material removed.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something specific about PDF/E that you require that is not long-term-preservation?  Is PDF/A (which is about long term preservation) sufficient?  PDF/E seems to be about "engineering workflows" more than long term storage.

If PDF/A is what you need, [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) and [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net) are libraries you can use from Java to produce PDF documents including PDF/A.  Just note that PDF/A as a long-term-safe-storage principle disables certain PDF features like external hyperlinks and passwords.